Pivot multiple columns in SQL Server
I have read Microsoft SQL Server docs about pivot feature and I sort of get the gist of how it works - but there is a bit of curve ball which I am unable to solve.
I have 4 tables, each contains orders info, invoice info, calculations, payments and from my understanding they would be considered un-pivoted.
After reading SQL Server Pivot docs, I put this query together which gives me a pivot of Tag column values.
For simplicity I joined only two out of 4 tables: Orders and Calculations and applied PIVOT()
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         OD.Date,
         OD.TicketNumber,
         OD.Tag,
         OD.SubTotal,
         TC.[Name] AS Calculation,
         TC.Amount
     FROM  
         @OrderData OD
     LEFT JOIN 
         @TicketCalculations TC ON TC.TicketId = OD.TicketId
     GROUP BY
         OD.Date, OD.TicketNumber,
         OD.Tag, OD.SubTotal, OD.TicketTotal,
         TC.Name, TC.Amount) AS src
PIVOT
    (SUM(src.SubTotal)
        FOR Tag IN (Food, Beer, Cocktail, Other)
    ) AS piv1




Date
TicketNumber
Calculation
Amount
Food
Beer
Cocktail
Other




2024-09-27
5
Round
-25.00
-
38.00
-
-


2024-09-27
6
Delivery Commission
-5.03
13.50
20.00
-
-


2024-09-27
6
Discount
-2.85
13.50
20.00
-
-


2024-10-01
7
-
-
-
2.00
-
-


2024-10-01
8
-
-
-
-
4.00
-


2024-10-01
9
-
-
8.50
-
-
-



However, I also want to pivot Calculations values with amounts followed by other tables.
This is my expected output:



Date
TicketNumber
Food
Soda
Beer
Cocktails
Other
SubTotal
Round
Discount
Delivery Commission
Total
Cash
QR
Card
Voucher
etc.




Sep-27
5
-
-
38
-
-
38
-25
-
-
13
13
-
-
-
-


Sep-27
6
13.5
-
20
-
-
33.5
-
-2.85
-5.03
25.62
20
5.62
-
-
-


Sep-27
7
-
-
2
-
-
2
-
-
-
2
-
-
-
-
-


Oct-01
8
-
-
-
4
-
4
-
-
-
4
-
-
-
-
-


Oct-01
9
8.5
-
-
-
-
8.5
-
-
-
8.5
-
-
-
-
-



Is there a way I can insert pivot table out into another variable table or temporary table? To JOIN with another which I will be pivoting? Or is there another way of achieving this?
I won't shy away from restructuring initial query if needed too.

I suggest looking into conditional aggregation, rather than the restrictive PIVOT operator.

This question is similar to: How to create a table from select query result in SQL Server 2008. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  (P.s. It's standard SQL, so not much has changed since 2008)

As pointed out by Thom A in the comments above, complex pivot operations are sometimes more easily performed using conditional aggregation as an alternative to the SQL PIVOT operation.
Conditional aggregation uses a combination of an aggregate function like COUNT() or SUM() together with an embedded CASE expression of IIF() function to conditionally select or exclude data.
You are likely also dealing with a table structure that has multiple one-to-many relationships (orders to details, orders to calculations, orders to payments, etc.). Just joining the tables in a single query can lead to cross products of rows and duplicate counting of aggregated results.
The solution is to isolate each one-to-many relationship in a subselect or a CROSS APPLY that selects and aggregates the data, so that the outer query only sees a single aggregated row.
Also, your apparent OrderData table is unusual in that it contains both order data (Date, TicketNumber) and order-detail data (Tag, SubTotal). Normal data design would separate this data into two tables.
For your original data structure, your query might look something like:
SELECT
    O.*,
    C.*,
    O.Subtotal + ISNULL(C.TotalAdjustments, 0) AS Total,
    P.*,
    O.Subtotal + ISNULL(C.TotalAdjustments, 0) - ISNULL(P.TotalPayments, 0) AS Balance
FROM (
    SELECT
         OD.TicketId,
         OD.Date,
         OD.TicketNumber,
         OD.TicketTotal,
         SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Food'     THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Food,
         SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Beer'     THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Beer,
         SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Cocktail' THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Cocktail,
         SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Other'    THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Other,
        --SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag NOT IN (...) THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Other,
         SUM(OD.SubTotal) AS Subtotal
    FROM OrderData OD
    GROUP BY OD.TicketId, OD.Date, OD.TicketNumber, OD.TicketTotal
) O
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN TC.Name = 'Round'               THEN TC.Amount END) AS Round,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TC.Name = 'Discount'            THEN TC.Amount END) AS Discount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TC.Name = 'Delivery Commission' THEN TC.Amount END) AS DeliveryCommission,
        SUM(TC.Amount) AS TotalAdjustments
    FROM TicketCalculations TC
    WHERE TC.TicketId = O.TicketId
) C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'Cash'    THEN P.Amount END) AS Cash,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'QR'      THEN P.Amount END) AS QR,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'Card'    THEN P.Amount END) AS Card,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'Voucher' THEN P.Amount END) AS Voucher,
        SUM(P.Amount) AS TotalPayments
    FROM Payments P
    WHERE P.TicketId = O.TicketId
) P

For separate Orders and OrderDetails tables, the query might look something like:
SELECT
    O.*,
    OD.*,
    C.*,
    OD.Subtotal + ISNULL(C.TotalAdjustments, 0) AS Total,
    P.*,
    OD.Subtotal + ISNULL(C.TotalAdjustments, 0) - ISNULL(P.TotalPayments, 0) AS Balance
FROM Orders O
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Food'     THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Food,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Beer'     THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Beer,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Cocktail' THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Cocktail,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Other'    THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Other,
        --SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag NOT IN (...) THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Other,
        SUM(OD.SubTotal) AS Subtotal
    FROM OrderDetails OD
    WHERE OD.TicketId = O.TicketId
) OD
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN TC.Name = 'Round'               THEN TC.Amount END) AS Round,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TC.Name = 'Discount'            THEN TC.Amount END) AS Discount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TC.Name = 'Delivery Commission' THEN TC.Amount END) AS DeliveryCommission,
        SUM(TC.Amount) AS TotalAdjustments
    FROM TicketCalculations TC
    WHERE TC.TicketId = O.TicketId
) C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'Cash'    THEN P.Amount END) AS Cash,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'QR'      THEN P.Amount END) AS QR,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'Card'    THEN P.Amount END) AS Card,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'Voucher' THEN P.Amount END) AS Voucher,
        SUM(P.Amount) AS TotalPayments
    FROM Payments P
    WHERE P.TicketId = O.TicketId
) P

You can also use left-joins to subqueries that aggregate all availabkle data as follows:
SELECT
    O.*,
    OD.*,
    C.*,
    OD.Subtotal + ISNULL(C.TotalAdjustments, 0) AS Total,
    P.*,
    OD.Subtotal + ISNULL(C.TotalAdjustments, 0) - ISNULL(P.TotalPayments, 0) AS Balance
FROM Orders O
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        OD.TicketId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Food'     THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Food,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Beer'     THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Beer,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Cocktail' THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Cocktail,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Other'    THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Other,
        --SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag NOT IN (...) THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS Other,
        SUM(OD.SubTotal) AS Subtotal
    FROM OrderDetails OD
    GROUP BY OD.TicketId
) OD
    ON OD.TicketId = O.TicketId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        TC.TicketId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TC.Name = 'Round'               THEN TC.Amount END) AS Round,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TC.Name = 'Discount'            THEN TC.Amount END) AS Discount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TC.Name = 'Delivery Commission' THEN TC.Amount END) AS DeliveryCommission,
        SUM(TC.Amount) AS TotalAdjustments
    FROM TicketCalculations TC
    GROUP BY TC.TicketId
) C
    ON C.TicketId = O.TicketId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        P.TicketId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'Cash'    THEN P.Amount END) AS Cash,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'QR'      THEN P.Amount END) AS QR,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'Card'    THEN P.Amount END) AS Card,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.Name = 'Voucher' THEN P.Amount END) AS Voucher,
        SUM(P.Amount) AS TotalPayments
    FROM Payments P
    GROUP BY P.TicketId
) P
    ON P.TicketId = O.TicketId

The disadvantage of the above is that each subselects aggregates all rows. If the outer query has conditions that filter the orders, the inner queries still aggregate all available data, unless the filter conditions are duplicated in each of those subqueries.
Sample Results:



Id
Date
TicketNumber
Food
Beer
Cocktail
Other
Subtotal
Round
Discount
DeliveryCommission
TotalAdjustments
Total
Cash
QR
Card
Voucher
TotalPayments
Balance




105
2024-09-27
5
null
38.00
null
null
38.00
-25.00
null
null
-25.00
13.00
13.00
null
null
null
13.00
0.00


106
2024-09-27
6
13.50
20.00
null
null
33.50
null
-2.85
-5.03
-7.88
25.62
20.00
5.62
null
null
25.62
0.00


107
2024-10-01
7
null
2.00
null
null
2.00
null
null
null
null
2.00
null
null
null
null
null
2.00


108
2024-10-01
8
null
null
4.00
null
4.00
null
null
null
null
4.00
null
null
null
null
null
4.00


109
2024-10-01
9
8.50
null
null
null
8.50
null
null
null
null
8.50
null
null
null
null
null
8.50



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
Your complete table schema was not provided, so the above only reflects the data and structure apparent from your post. You should be able to adapt and extend the above to match your actual environment.

Thanks for the extensive response, I've learned something new going through this!
I should have probably mentioned this but the reason why I am opting for Pivot is because Tags (Food, Beer etc. ) / Calculations (Discount etc.) & Payments (Cash, QR etc.) are user defined, there is no way of knowing what they will be ahead of time.
Before my 4 tables are generated there is about 500 lines of SQL query consolidating and processing information, for simplicity I didn't want to include it all.

Without knowing the values ahead of time, there will be no option other than dynamic SQL, but that would be the case whether you use pivot or conditional aggregation. Also, take a look at QUOTENAME() function for use when injecting identifiers and string literals. For example, given a Tag value of Hors d'oeuvres, QUOTENAME(Tag) will yield [Hors d'oeuvres] and QUOTENAME(Tag, '''') will yield 'Hors d''oeuvres'. Useful to safely generate the dynamic select item SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Tag = 'Hors d''oeuvres' THEN OD.SubTotal END) AS [Hors d'oeuvres].

+1 for the comprehensive answer, but worth noting that this part is wrong - "The disadvantage of the above is that each subselects aggregates all rows. If the outer query has conditions that filter the orders, the inner queries still aggregate all available data, unless the filter conditions are duplicated in each of those subqueries." - SQL Server can and will push predicates up into subqueries without the predicate being explicitly duplicated. This is something I touch upon in this answer

This can also be demonstrated with your fiddle. After adding a filter to the outer query in both the apply and the join methods, both yield the same plan, with the scans on the 3 tables in the subqueries being limited with the outer predicate - https://dbfiddle.uk/70ejnKSz

@GarethD - Interesting. I didn't know the engine would do that. However, I added more data plus some indexes and ran a few more tests with various filter conditions (fiddle) and found that there are limitations. If the execution plan uses loop joins, the subselects translate to the equivalent of the cross-apply, and only the needed rows are retrieved. If a hash (or merge) join is used, the behavior seems to depend on whether the filter condition can be directly applied to the subquery based on the join condition. ...

... A TicketId filter will propagate, but an order Date filter will not. In the latter case, table (or index) scans can occur in the subqueries. I also tried performing a preselect into a @SelectedIds table variable, and then using that as the main query filter, but the subselects still performed tables scans. Other scenarios are likely possible with different combinations of test data row counts and filter ranges, but trying to manipulate the query optimizer is a tricky business. There's always the 'LOOP' join hint, but that's a whole new rabbit hole.

In all those cases it is not that SQL server can't push the predicate up, it is that it has elected that for such a small data set it is more efficient to pre-aggregate all the data and merge/hash join rather than do nested loops. Increasing the number of orders from 500 to 50,000 yields a different plan where predicates are again nested loops are used even with filters on order date etc. Generally though, I agree "trying to manipulate the query optimizer is a tricky business", which was kind of my point, using apply over join does not guarantee anything in terms of execution plan.

Paul White has written about this in a fair bit of detail here, and the conclusion is that "the optimizer can often convert an apply into a join, and can pretty much always consider an apply alternative to a join.", as such my preference is to always use join syntax where possible, as it is more likely my join can be converted to an apply if it is more efficient than vice versa. It often won't make a difference either way, but removing outer references gives the optimiser more plan options to explore.
